# How to get Primary Key on SQL Update?

Tags: sql, t-sql, primary-key

I'm updating a table if "searchedWord" is found.  If it is found I would like to know what the primary key is for the record I just updated.  How would I do this?  Below is my code.  On a side note, if "searchedWord" is not found I insert it and use scope_identity() to get it.  My problem is how to do the same with Update? I guess I could do a select statement first but that is an additional query.

```
BEGIN TRAN    
    UPDATE COBC_searchedWord 
    SET searchCount=searchCount+1, 
        resultsReturned=#resultsReturned#, 
        lastSearched=getDate() 
    WHERE searchedWord='#searchedWord#';

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO COBC_searchedWord
            ([searchedWord] ,[searchCount] ,[resultsReturned] ,[lastSearched])
        VALUES
            ('#searchedWord#',1,'#resultsReturned#',getDate())
        SELECT scope_identity() AS searchedWordID
    END
COMMIT TRAN
```

Update: This is what I ended up with and it seems to work. Thanks for the input.

```
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE (ID int);  
UPDATE COBC_searchedWord
SET searchCount=searchCount+1, 
    resultsReturned=#resultsReturned#, 
    lastSearched=getDate()  
OUTPUT inserted.searchedWordID into @tmpTable          
WHERE searchedWord='#searchedWord#';          

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0  
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO COBC_searchedWord  
        ([searchedWord])         
        OUTPUT inserted.searchedWordID into @tmpTable  
    VALUES  
        ('#searchedWord#');  
END  
SELECT ID from @tmpTable;
```

Comment: The primary key does not change. It's part of the scheme. You need to know it prior to your query. To me it does not make sense to find it out dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the OUTPUT cluase. Books online will explain how.

Comment: More information and examples are here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/01/sql-server-2005-output-clause-example-and-explanation-with-insert-update-delete/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you are updating your record, and that searchword focund in table then select the searchedWordID from table

```
BEGIN TRAN    
    UPDATE COBC_searchedWord 
    SET searchCount=searchCount+1, 
        resultsReturned=#resultsReturned#, 
        lastSearched=getDate() 
    WHERE searchedWord='#searchedWord#';

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO COBC_searchedWord
            ([searchedWord] ,[searchCount] ,[resultsReturned] ,[lastSearched])
        VALUES
            ('#searchedWord#',1,'#resultsReturned#',getDate())
        SELECT scope_identity() AS searchedWordID
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      SELECT searchedWordID FROM COBC_searchedWord 
      WHERE searchedWord='#searchedWord#';
    END
COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: There is no reason to do any extra SELECT when the information is readily available from the UPDATE via the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: But don't you have use a select anyway to get the information from the OUTPUT clause? see update above.